# How to test if a cable modem is functional?

Tags: cable-modem

I have an old Motorola Surfboard SB6120 that I bought used and never used. It has some light rust on irrelevant parts mostly around the lan port support bracket and on the cable tuner shield, and it lights up. What tests can I do to see whether it functions correctly?

Would save me 110-130$ without lifting a finger so that's why I ask, it take dust anyway ...

Power is green, receive is a blinking blue, link is orange, obviously online isn't up light and send too cause it's not on an isp service for now.

Led chart :
https://secure.dslreports.com/r0/download/1588034~9aef8c4c2656e0fd7ba6c298bb1d9b25/SB6120%20LED.gif

The configuration page of the modem work, could I consider it fully fonctionnal ?

Logs in case if something suspicious would hint about a potential trouble :

```
This page displays detailed information intended for use by an authorized Motorola Corporation Cable Modem technician.

Time    Priority    Code    Message

Jan 01 1970 00:00:13    6-Notice    N/A Cable Modem Reboot due to power reset ;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:35:34    3-Critical  T05.0   SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Loss of Sync;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:34:38    7-Information   B401.0  Authorized;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:34:34    6-Notice    I401.0  TLV-11 - unrecognized OID;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:34:34    5-Warning   Z00.0   MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 01 1970 00:00:18    3-Critical  R02.0   No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 01 1970 00:00:13    6-Notice    N/A Cable Modem Reboot from shell ;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:33:47    6-Notice    E112.0  SW download Successful - Via Config file

Jan 15 2013 19:32:21    6-Notice    E102.0  SW Download INIT - Via Config file cxv9873254k;fg87dsfd;kf

Jan 15 2013 19:32:21    7-Information   B401.0  Authorized;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:32:17    6-Notice    I401.0  TLV-11 - unrecognized OID;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:32:01    3-Critical  R02.0   No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:31:45    6-Notice    I401.0  TLV-11 - unrecognized OID;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 15 2013 19:31:45    5-Warning   Z00.0   MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=1;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 01 1970 00:00:12    6-Notice    N/A Cable Modem Reboot due to power reset ;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=c4:64:13:fa:6b:7c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jun 18 2010 10:16:56    3-Critical  R04.0   Received Response to Broadcast Maintenance Request, But no Unicast Maintenance opportunities received - T4 time out;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:14:f1:ea:66:5a;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jun 18 2010 10:16:46    3-Critical  T05.0   SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Loss of Sync;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:14:f1:ea:66:5a;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jun 16 2010 09:18:06    7-Information   B401.0  Authorized;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:14:f1:ea:66:5a;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 01 1970 00:00:12    6-Notice    N/A Cable Modem Reboot due to T4 timeout ;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:14:f1:ea:66:5a;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Jan 01 1970 00:00:12    4-Error T201.0  Missing Mandatory MDD TLV on primary DS Channel;CM-MAC=00:22:10:39:5b:ad;CMTS-MAC=00:14:f1:ea:66:5a;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
```

Comment: without an active connection to CMTS, a cable modem's functionality and therefore testability is limited.

Comment: @zillion Are you trying to test it without first authorizing it on your ISP?

Comment: Actually it would be used for my future internet connection but isps around here don't provide much support on that point, it may cost me up to 150$ if the modem don't work if I just activate the connection to try it, as I would pay an added activation fee and a new cable modem ...

Comment: wow this is a very clear overview of the **LED status** of the modem. http://moto.arrisi.com/staticfiles/Video-Solutions/_Documents/User_guides/Static_files/SURFboard%20DOCSIS%203.0%20eXtreme%20Cable%20Modems%20Pocket%20Guide.pdf What is your LED/modem status?

Comment: Power is green, receive is a blinking blue, link is orange, obviously online isn't up light and send too cause it's not on an isp service for now ...

Comment: you won't know for sure if it works unless you put it on where there's an isp and you browse the internet, and even then you won't know for sure 'cos it's just that time that it worked! try browsing for a few weeks see if any problems then make a decision that it seems to work ok, no problems noticed yet!

Comment: Read my update in my answer.

Comment: @MaQleod I think you should throw your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surfboard modems do have an internal configuration page, and will give out a DHCP address even when not connected to the internet. Try connecting via ethernet directly to the modem, then run the following in the command prompt (assuming you have a Windows computer):

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

Wait for the computer to acquire an IP address. You should get an IP in the format of `192.168.x.x` - in my experience it'll give you a `192.168.100.x` address, but I've only ever tried this on one modem. Now, open your browser and go to `192.168.x.1`, replacing the `x` with whatever the third number is.

This should give you the modem's configuration and info page.

Comment: Why not `/release` first and then `/renew`

Comment: @DibloDk either should work - when you do `/renew`, it releases first.

Comment: I believe that if he has a wrong ip (self assigned) then you should release it, otherwise it will be renewed because of self assigned Lease Time. (Windows DHCP client)

Comment: @DibloDk I'm not sure, but you may be correct. Just in case, I'll update the answer, but if you can find any reference for that I'd be interested to see.

Comment: The only thing I have is `... discard the IP address configuration for enten all adapters ... This parameter disables TCP/IP for adapters configured to obtain an IP address automatically.` ( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows?query=Ipconfig%20%2Frenew&Refinement=1002&ac=2#refinementChanges=&pageNumber=2&showMore=false ) and some old memory about `/renew` only perform new assignment and renewal of the Lease Time. But I will see what I can find.

Comment: If the configuration page of the modem could I trust it that it will work fine ?

Comment: If the configuration page of the modem what?

Comment: IS it dead Jim or it will work for a new isp service ?

Comment: @zillion are you saying that you were able to load the config page? If so, the modem probably works but there's no way to truly verify that without having ISP service to test it with.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a config page for surfboards.  It was at 192.168.100.1 or something like that...  It wasnt an address you would think to use.

Comment: @Keltari that's what I'm saying :)

Comment: @zillion this suggests it will likely work - I know with Charter here in Reno, if you're switching modems, all you need to do is call them up, read them the numbers off your new modem, and voila, good to go.  If you're getting new service, tell them you have a modem already, and they'll get it up and running - worst case is it won't work, and the tech will likely just need to go out to his/her van and get you a new modem.

Comment: Perfect then !!! ;)

Comment: duno which windows vresions maybe xp maybe 7 dunno if 8. but there's also right clicking network connection and repair which is similar to or involves release and repair.

Comment: @barlop that'll renew the DHCP address but it won't tell you what the new address is, which is necessary for finding the config page.

Comment: @nhinkle  right click, then  status, then details, ip is there. http://www.microcenter.com/images/email/random_access/2007/1007/29StatusDetail.jpg

Answer (score -1):

If you think you may be lucky and want to keep it simple, try:

Press `Win + R` button down simultaneously; *Run opens.*

Type `cmd` and press enter; *The command prompt opens.*

Type `ping google.com` and press enter.
This will return

```
Pinging google.com [X.X.X.X] with X bytes of data:
Reply from X.X.X.X: bytes=X time=Xms TTL=X
Reply from X.X.X.X: bytes=X time=Xms TTL=X
Reply from X.X.X.X: bytes=X time=Xms TTL=X
Reply from X.X.X.X: bytes=X time=Xms TTL=X
Reply from X.X.X.X: bytes=X time=Xms TTL=X

Ping statistics for X.X.X.X:
    Packets: Sent = X, Received = X, Lost = X (X% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = Xms, Maximum = Xms, Average = Xms
```

The X will be replace by a number, and hopefully Lost/loss will be 0.

If Lost is not 0, then try with.

Type `ping 8.8.8.8` and press enter

And if Lost is still not 0, then you need a lot more help than just a simple test which MaQleod said.

**UPDATE:**
Read section "Signing up and services" in the manual
http://www.wavebroadband.com/support/internet/docs/SB6120-Cable-Modem-User-Guide.pdf

> **Signing Up for Service**
> You must sign up with an Internet Service provider to access the Internet and othér online services. To activate your service, call your local Internet service provider.
>
> To receive data service, you need to provide the MAC address printed on the bar code label marked CM HFC MAC ID on the bottom of the cable modem. You can record it here:
> `00::____:____:____:____`
>
> You should ask your Internet Service provider the following questions:
>
> - Do you have any special system requirements?
> - When can I begin to use my SB6120?
> - Are there any files I need to download after connecting the SB6120?
> - Do I need a user name or password to access the Internet or use e-mail?

Comment: And nhinkle have already give you more help if it don't work :)

Comment: That's what I would do. It's a bit like asking how to check if a lightbulb works.

Comment: This won't work unless the cable modem is already registered with your cable ISP . . .

Comment: Yes, but it will tell us whether it works or not, and it takes 2 minutes. Then we find out if it is setup, ISP or something thr is the problem.

Comment: Not subscribed, the modem has been taken cause I hardly trust Thomson DCM475 cable modem sold by the isp and the Motorola Surfboard SB6120 is usable on the isp service ...

Comment: Then I think that you will not get it to work, with memories your IPS is willing to give you the setting info for your cable modem. And that does not mean you get it to work. But it sounds to nhinkle is the one who knows your modem.

Comment: Diblo Dk I can't say, I had it dirt cheap in a flea market so I pick up ...

Comment: You have everything you need now. I still hope that you succeed, but it is up to your ISP.